# Passing an array of data as an input parameter to an Oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm trying to pass an array of (`varchar`) data into an Oracle procedure. The Oracle procedure would be either called from SQL*Plus or from another PL/SQL procedure like so:

```
BEGIN
 pr_perform_task('1','2','3','4');
END;
```

`pr_perform_task` will read each of the input parameters and perform the tasks.

I'm not sure as to how I can achieve this. My first thought was to use an input parameter of type `varray` but I'm getting `Error: PLS-00201: identifier 'VARRAY' must be declared` error, when the procedure definiton looks like this:

`CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PR_DELETE_RECORD_VARRAY(P_ID VARRAY) IS`

To summarize, how can I pass the data as an array, let the SP loop through each of the parameters and perform the task ?

I'm using Oracle 10gR2 as my database.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MyType AS VARRAY(200) OF VARCHAR2(50);
  2  /

Type created

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testing (t_in MyType) IS
  2  BEGIN
  3    FOR i IN 1..t_in.count LOOP
  4      dbms_output.put_line(t_in(i));
  5    END LOOP;
  6  END;
  7  /

Procedure created

SQL> DECLARE
  2    v_t MyType;
  3  BEGIN
  4    v_t := MyType();
  5    v_t.EXTEND(10);
  6    v_t(1) := 'this is a test';
  7    v_t(2) := 'A second test line';
  8    testing(v_t);
  9  END;
 10  /

this is a test
A second test line
```

To expand on my comment to @dcp's answer, here's how you could implement the solution proposed there if you wanted to use an associative array:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE p IS
  2    TYPE p_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  3  
  4    PROCEDURE pp (inp p_type);
  5  END p;
  6  /

Package created
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY p IS
  2    PROCEDURE pp (inp p_type) IS
  3    BEGIN
  4      FOR i IN 1..inp.count LOOP
  5        dbms_output.put_line(inp(i));
  6      END LOOP;
  7    END pp;
  8  END p;
  9  /

Package body created
SQL> DECLARE
  2    v_t p.p_type;
  3  BEGIN
  4    v_t(1) := 'this is a test of p';
  5    v_t(2) := 'A second test line for p';
  6    p.pp(v_t);
  7  END;
  8  /

this is a test of p
A second test line for p

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL>
```

This trades creating a standalone Oracle TYPE (which cannot be an associative array) with requiring the definition of a package that can be seen by all in order that the TYPE it defines there can be used by all.

Comment: Nice answer. I wondered if it's possible to do what your first method does, but for the situation where the number of elements in `t_in` is dynamic (that is, it's different for each call to `testing`)? It seems like one needs to at least hard code an upper bounds for `MyType`? Can that restriction be lifted somehow?

Comment: @ggkmath, it does not matter how large the array is, but you must declare the VARRAY upper limit when you create or alter the TYPE.

Comment: Is there alternate solution that can accommodate such dynamic size, perhaps without VARRAY? If off topic, I can start a new thread.

Comment: Use the second half of the answer - make the type a PL/SQL associative array and define it in the package spec.

Comment: For me I had to initialize the table type using the following v_t p.p_type = p.p_type();  later call v_t.extend(10) to create space for 10 elements. Not sure why it is different from what you are doing and what I have. Btween I have created a table_type of a type that we created

Comment: Regarding the inflexible limit for varrays, you can use a nested table collection type instead of a varray: `create or replace type mytype as table of varchar2(50);` I generally wouldn't recommend varrays for use in PL/SQL programing as they have some major limitations.

Answer (score 8):

If the types of the parameters are all the same (`varchar2` for example), you can have a package like this which will do the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE testuser.test_pkg IS

   TYPE assoc_array_varchar2_t IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

   PROCEDURE your_proc(p_parm IN assoc_array_varchar2_t);

END test_pkg;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY testuser.test_pkg IS

   PROCEDURE your_proc(p_parm IN assoc_array_varchar2_t) AS
   BEGIN
      FOR i IN p_parm.first .. p_parm.last
      LOOP
         dbms_output.put_line(p_parm(i));
      END LOOP;

   END;

END test_pkg;
```

Then, to call it you'd need to set up the array and pass it:

```
DECLARE
  l_array testuser.test_pkg.assoc_array_varchar2_t;
BEGIN
  l_array(0) := 'hello';
  l_array(1) := 'there';  

  testuser.test_pkg.your_proc(l_array);
END;
/
```

Comment: You can't create an Oracle Type of associative array. The only way this can work is by defining the type in a package and referencing it that way.

Comment: @DCookie - My fault, thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have corrected my answer :).

Comment: Is It necesary create a package?

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question. Except for a few rare cases, you should *always* use packages, refer here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7452431376537

Answer (score 0):

You may user like:

1. Create table types. user below command

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE StringListType AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1024);
   ```
2. Create Procedure:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PR_DELETE_RECORD_VARRAY(
       pList  IN StringListType
   ) AS
   BEGIN

       FOR i IN 1..pList.COUNT LOOP
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('item: ' || pList(i));
         /*
          write logic here
        */
       END LOOP;
   END;
   ```
3. Call the procedure:

   ```
   DECLARE
       vList StringListType := StringListType('1', '2', '3');

   BEGIN
       PR_DELETE_RECORD_VARRAY(pList => vList);
   END;
   /
   ```