# Oracle SQL insert query - into parent and child tables

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

for an assignment I had something similar to the following (simplified for brevity):

```
STUDENT(StudentID, Fname. Lname)  StudentID PK
UNIT(UnitID, UnitName)            UnitID PK
STUDENT_UNIT((StudentID, UnitID)  StudentID PK/FK UnitID PK/FK
```

Needed to insert info about a student and the units that he/she had completed.
As it is only beginner level SQL the following was accepted

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT
VALUES(seqStudID.NextVal, 'Bob', 'Brown');

INSERT INTO STUDENT_UNIT(seqStudID.CurrVal, 111);

INSERT INTO STUDENT_UNIT(seqStudID.CurrVal, 222);

INSERT INTO STUDENT_UNIT(seqStudID.CurrVal, 333);
```

But I was wondering what would be the real way to enter this data, would it be a procedure with a loop? If so what sort of loop (so that it could handle any amount of units).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best approach to do this is by using `stored procedure`. The below procedure will do everything for you.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE set_stud_unit(
          i_fname IN VARCHAR2,
          i_lname IN VARCHAR2,
          i_unitid IN VARCHAR2)
IS
     l_studentid student.studentid%TYPE;
BEGIN

     INSERT INTO student(studentid, fname, lname)
          VALUES(seqstudid.NEXTVAL, i_fname, i_lname)
          RETURNING studentid INTO l_studentid;

     INSERT INTO student_unit (studentid, unitid)
          (SELECT l_studentid, (COLUMN_VALUE).getNumberVal() vid FROM xmltable(i_unitid));

     COMMIT;

END;     
/
```

You can pass the unitid as comma separated as below,

```
EXECUTE set_stud_unit('Bob', 'Brown', '111,222,333');
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try all of the suggestions on the page.

Comment: Hi, this worked for the example shown. Can you tell me how I would implement it if the STUDENT_UNIT table required more columns. say something like Semester, Year and Grade? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can use select in your insert:

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT_UNIT select t1.StudentID ,t2.UnitID from STUDENT t1 ,UNIT t2;
```

and you can use where to limit this selection ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try all of the suggestions on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you need is a procedure that accept:

- First Name
- Last Name
- an array of Units

The procedure will:

- Insert into STUDENT (I suggest you to use a trigger to populate StudentID, maybe you are already doing it),
- Loop over the array and insert into STUDENT_UNIT each of the element of the array and the StudentID for First Name and Last Name, but without using the sequence. My pseudo code:

  ```
  FOR i IN 1..input_array.count LOOP
      INSERT INTO STUDENT_UNIT
      SELECT StudentID, input_array(i)
        FROM STUDENT
       WHERE Fname = FirstNameParam
         AND Lname = LastNameParam;
  END LOOP;
  ```

I suggest you to query the student table to get the actual ID to avoid problems in case of concurrency. An optimization would be to query the STUDENT table only once and save the StudentID in a variable.

You can find more info about passing an array to an Oracle procedure here:
[Passing an array of data as an input parameter to an Oracle procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885575/passing-an-array-of-data-as-an-input-parameter-to-an-oracle-procedure)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try all of the suggestions on the page.