# Auto updated foreign table keys when new data arrives (OracleDB)

Tags: oracle, plsql, automation

Is there a technique in OracleDB to automatically generate and maintain foreign tables?
For simplicity, let's say I have table with two columns: FirstName and Country.
If I create this table MyData like:

```
    FirstName varchar2(200)
    Country varchar2(100)
```

It will take too much space if I have millions of records and it is sure there will be just small ammount of unique countries and first names.
What would be much better is to create foreign tables:

```
    FirstName_TB: ID unique number, FirstName varchar2(200)
    Country_TB: ID unique number, Contry varchar2(100)
    MyData: FirstName number, Country number.
```

To do it in theory is quite simple. When new record is to be created, I will lookup into foreign table for correct ID and put it into MyTable. If there is no record in foreign table, new records will be created.

Imagine I have dozens of columns and dozens of millions of records, in data loader part I would need to hold all foreign key values in memory, have trouble running it in parallel etc.

So my question is, is there any technique in OracleDB to achieve this?
Something like:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstName, Country) VALUES ("Tomas","Netherland")
```

**but instead of inserting raw strings into MyTable, it will find/create foreign table keys and use just IDs in MyTable?**
I was thinking about some before insert trigger to do all the heavy lifting here, but I guess it will be quite slow. Also it is such common task, I would bet there is some technique or procedure to achieve this on DB level with the best performance.

Went through google and stackoverflow for suggestions without any luck.

Comment: I hope this is not a real example (because normalization on column basis makes storage cheaper but processing becomes very costly). But for this task you may use procedure as an API with `returning` clause to get FK value. [Oracle SQL insert query - into parent and child tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463268/oracle-sql-insert-query-into-parent-and-child-tables)

Comment: Thank you. I thought there is some built-in mechanism to do this, because it is common problem. I can solve it on "data load" side when I download whole FK table in memory and send only IDs to oracle and invoke only inserts to FK table when necessary, otherwise I won't touch it.
BTW, I have indexes on all columns, and the table (from what oracle gives me) is quite small, but indexes are quite big. Isn't it possible that oracle cleverly do this on the background if there is an index on the column? I was hoping there is some keyword saying the column should be treated as auto FK or something:)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE add_mydata(
  i_firstname IN FirstNames.FirstName%TYPE,
  i_country   IN Countries.Country%TYPE
)
IS
  v_fn_id FirstNames.ID%TYPE;
  v_c_id  Countries.ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    SELECT id
    INTO   v_fn_id
    FROM   FirstNames
    WHERE  FirstName = i_firstname;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      INSERT INTO FirstNames (FirstName)
      VALUES (i_firstname)
      RETURNING id INTO v_fn_id;
  END;

  BEGIN
    SELECT id
    INTO   v_c_id
    FROM   Countries
    WHERE  Country = i_country;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      INSERT INTO Countries (Country)
      VALUES (i_country)
      RETURNING id INTO v_c_id;
  END;

  INSERT INTO MyData (FirstName, Country)
  VALUES (v_fn_id, v_c_id);
END;
/
```

Which, for the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE FirstNames (
  ID        NUMBER
            GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
            PRIMARY KEY,
  FirstName varchar2(200)
            UNIQUE
            NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Countries (
  ID        NUMBER
            GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
            PRIMARY KEY,
  Country   varchar2(100)
            UNIQUE
            NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE MyData (
  FirstName REFERENCES FirstNames,
  Country   REFERENCES Countries
);
```

Then, calling the procedure:

```sql
BEGIN
  add_mydata('Alice', 'Austria');
  add_mydata('Betty', 'Brazil');
  add_mydata('Carol', 'Cambodia');
  add_mydata('Alice', 'Brazil');
  add_mydata('Carol', 'Austria');
END;
/
```

Results in the tables containing:

```sql
SELECT m.*, f.firstname, c.country
FROM   mydata m
       INNER JOIN FirstNames f
       ON (m.firstname = f.id)
       INNER JOIN Countries c
       ON (m.country = c.id);
```

| FIRSTNAME | COUNTRY | FIRSTNAME | COUNTRY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Alice | Austria |
| 3 | 1 | Carol | Austria |
| 2 | 2 | Betty | Brazil |
| 1 | 2 | Alice | Brazil |
| 3 | 3 | Carol | Cambodia |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/R5MtHCWC)

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was afraid. I thought (hoped) there is something built-in, because it seems using procedure will be very slow. I guess I will need to hold foreign tables in memory on the side of "data loader", load whole foreign table in memory at the beginning and invoke insert into foreign table only when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This is what PL/SQL is good at. There is no need to pull all this data outside the database and do the lookups in client/loader code. For optimal performance:

1. Create a staging table. If using SQL*Loader, it should be a real table (though there is a hacky workaround to use temporary tables, but that is beyond the scope of this answer). If you wrote your own loader and have the ability to invoke a procedure *in the same session* as the data loading after the load is done, then you should create a temporary table.
2. Load the data into the staging table
3. Call a PL/SQL procedure to process the data. It will read the staging table and transform your data into your normalized structure.

   3a. For your lookup tables the best performing method is to use MERGEs against the dimension tables to update them with new/changed values found in the staging table. It only requires one SQL execution per dimension table, because you do all the rows together at once.

   3b. Then an INSERT (or another MERGE) to load your fact table using a query that joins in all the dimensions to get their keys. The keys will all be present because you loaded any new ones in step #3a.

This works a lot better for big data than a cursor that does row-by-row lookups on every dimension key. These operations can also take advantage of PQ, PDML, nologging and direct path, all of which are unavailable to row-by-row lookups.

Lastly, don't go overboard on normalization. Normalizing country might make sense (if you have any other attributes about each country), but I wouldn't normalize first or last name if that's the only person data you have. If, however, your fact table is below the grain of a person (e.g. a repeatable event that the same person could be involved in multiple times), you definitely want to pull all the person attributes (like name, address, email, etc.) out of that fact table into a person dimension. Normalization is more about having one source of truth and protecting data relationships than it is about saving space.