# Pass multiple values to a single parameter in PL/SQL and insert them into a table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to pass a multiple values like `'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12'` on as a single parameter and insert them into a table.

I have a scenario like saving a bill for particular customer, the customer might have purchased multiple items.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885575/passing-an-array-of-data-as-an-input-parameter-to-an-oracle-procedure

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS005

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the values comma separated.  This PL/SQL procedure breaks up a comma-separated string (passed as `P_VALUE`) and inserts each token into a table as a separate row, along with some other values.

```
PROCEDURE XXXXGL_INST_PARAMS (P_VALUE VARCHAR2) IS
    i          number;
    n          number;
    r          number;
    pos        number;
    L_NAT_ACCT varchar2(10);
    L_UID      number;
BEGIN
    L_UID := fnd_global.user_id;
    n := length(P_VALUE);
    i := 1;
    r := 1;

    WHILE (i < n) LOOP
        pos := (INSTR(P_VALUE,',',1,r)-i);
        IF pos < 0 THEN
            pos := n;
        END IF;
        SELECT substr(P_VALUE,i,pos) INTO L_NAT_ACCT FROM dual;

        INSERT INTO xxXXX.xxXXXgl_natural_accts_t
            (NATURAL_ACCT, CREATION_DATE, CREATED_BY, LAST_UPDATE_LOGIN, 
             LAST_UPDATE_DATE, LAST_UPDATED_BY)
          VALUES(L_NAT_ACCT,SYSDATE,L_UID,L_UID,SYSDATE,L_UID);

        i := i + length(L_NAT_ACCT)+1;
        r := r+1;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Note: I found this [here](http://oraclearea51.com/forums/welcome-to-oraclearea51-forum/645-how-to-pass-a-multiple-values-to-a-single-parameter-in-plsql.html).

Comment: much better (i didn't down vote, but i did vote up for the improvement)