# How Sql Procedure return mulltiple values with IN OUT :PLS-00103 error

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

i was using oracle 10g i want to make a sql procedure that return mulltiple values i am using IN OUT in my procedure

```
    create or replace procedure proc_mull_val
(
e_id in chr_emgt_employee.employee_code%type,
head_id out chr_emgt_employee.employee_code%type,
zone_id out chr_emgt_employee.employee_code%type
)
is
begin

SELECT   (SELECT   employee_code
            FROM   chr_emgt_employee
           WHERE   EMPLOYEE_ID = emgt1.SUPERVISOR_EMP_ID)
            , (SELECT   employee_code
                                FROM   chr_emgt_employee
                               WHERE   employee_id = EMGT2.SUPERVISOR_EMP_ID)

  INTO   head_id,zone_id
  FROM   chr_emgt_employee emgt1, chr_emgt_employee emgt2
 WHERE   EMGT2.employee_id = emgt1.SUPERVISOR_EMP_ID
         AND emgt1.employee_code = e_id;

end;
```

procedure is successfuly created but when i execute this

```
declare
head_id  chr_emgt_employee.employee_code%type;
zone_id  chr_emgt_employee.employee_code%type;
begin
execute proc_mull_val(151018,head_id,zone_id);
end;
```

i face this error when i execute it

***PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PROC_MULL_VAL" when expecting one of the following:
   := . ( @ % ; immediate
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "PROC_MULL_VAL" to continue.***

if someone has better suggestion about this query or my question then please inform me

Comment: Remove the `execute` in call to your procedure. Besides, your procedure seems to insert many values into variables; if you need to do so, you'll better think of `BULK COLLECT` and data structures

Comment: yes my procedure  insert a subquery in variable. but i am sorry i am not getting you **BULK COLLECT** what is that

Comment: So, if one of your queries can return more than one value, you can not use a single variable. Try something like:`DECLARE
    TYPE t_tab IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

    tab    t_tab;
BEGIN
        SELECT LEVEL
          BULK COLLECT INTO tab
          FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL < 3;

    for i in tab.first .. tab.last loop
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Size: ' || tab(i));
    end loop;
END;
/`

Comment: Do you mean multiple values as in a single scalar value in each of the two OUT parameters, so you get one value of each from a call to the procedure; or you want to retrieve multiple head_id and/or multiple zone_id values from a single call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your procedure has no issue just your way of calling is change

```
   DECLARE
   head_id   varchar2 (20);
   zone_id   varchar2 (20);
BEGIN
   proc_mull_val ('151018', head_id, zone_id);

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (head_id || '..... ' || zone_id);
END;
```

just try this and tell me if not solve change the data type and try again

Comment: thanks you are very close the issue is with data type i am big fool sorry and thanks for your patient

Answer (score 0):

Execute is an [SQL*PLUS comand](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12022.htm) thus you cannot use it inside a pl/sql anonymous block.

Answer (score 0):

First create collection object in your database. and use that collection object as out parameter.
Refer [Passing an array of data as an input parameter to an Oracle procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885575/passing-an-array-of-data-as-an-input-parameter-to-an-oracle-procedure)