# Passing array to Oracle procedure from c#

Tags: c#, arrays, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm trying to pass an array to oracle procedure. I searched about it and firstly i created a type named 'dizi' (like here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885575/passing-an-array-of-data-as-an-input-parameter-to-an-oracle-procedure)). So it works in oracle developer. The problem is; i can't pass my c# array to procedure as a parameter. So how can i pass my array to my procedure?

Here is my code (When i execute, oracle error says: Not all variables bound)

```C#
public void InsertQuestion(List<string> area_list)
{
    quest_areas = area_list.ToArray();
    command.Connection = connect;
    connect.Open();

    var arry = command.Parameters.Add("Areas", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
    arry.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    arry.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
    arry.Value = quest_areas;


    command.CommandText ="TESTPROCEDURE(:Areas)";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connect.Close();
}
```

Comment: You are already doing it `command.Parameters.Add` adding the `DbParameter`, internally `OracleParameter`

Comment: But it doesn't work?

Comment: What's the error, can you check ODP.Net sample

Comment: I think you missed `arry.Size = quest_areas.Length;`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Error is:Not all variables bound

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Oh sorry, i can set the size array's lenght. I just notice that sorry about my previous command. I'll try it now

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Not working. Error is: Not all veriables bound.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Define an array type and a procedure:

   ```
   CREATE or replace PACKAGE Testpackage AS 
     TYPE Areas_t is table of VARCHAR(100) index by BINARY_INTEGER;
     PROCEDURE TESTPROCEDURE(Areas IN Areas_t);       
   END Testpackage;
   ```
2. C# routine:

   ```
   public void InsertQuestion(IEnumerable<string> area_list)
   {
       var connect = new OracleConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING");

       var command = new OracleCommand("BEGIN Testpackage.Testprocedure(:Areas); END;", connect);

       connect.Open();

       var arry = command.Parameters.Add("Areas", OracleDbType.Varchar2);

       arry.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
       arry.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
       arry.Value = area_list.ToArray();
       arry.Size = area_list.Count();
       arry.ArrayBindSize = area_list.Select(_ => _.Length).ToArray();
       arry.ArrayBindStatus = Enumerable.Repeat(OracleParameterStatus.Success, area_list.Count()).ToArray();

       command.ExecuteNonQuery();

       connect.Close();
   }
   ```

Comment: Would you be kind enough to enrich this example so as to show how to use 'Areas' inside the implementation of TESTPROCEDURE? Thank you in advance.

Comment: seems like you don't need a bunch of parameters like Size,Direction, ArrayBindSize, ArrayBindStatus?

Comment: Side note: `IEnumerable.ToArray()` requires System.Linq.