# How to check value exist of an input param value as a list against a PL/SQL variable value?

Tags: c#, plsql

C# variable

```
string val_1 = 'A','B','C';
```

I pass this variable as a PL/SQL method parameter and check a value of another variable in the PL/SQL method as follows:

```
Procedure x(val_1 IN VARCHAR2)
IS
    val_2  VARCHAR2(1):= 'A';
BEGIN
    IF (val_2 IN (val_1)) THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('matched');
    END IF;
END;
```

This condition is not working. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `val_1` looks like just a string containing commas and quotes. For `val_2` to match it, it would have to have the value `'A','B','C'`. You probably need to pass in a nested table array and use `if val_2 member of val_1`, or an associative array and loop through its values, or keep the string and match using a regex. (I'd make this an answer but I'm a bit short of time right now.)

Comment: perhaps `if ','||val1||',' like '%,'||val2||',%' then ...`? Your initial string looks a little suspect, though - are you actually passing in `'A', 'B', 'C'`, or are you passing `A, B, C`?

Comment: Both ways are not working

Comment: Please answer my question regarding the exact string that you're passing in.

Comment: Yes, I tried both of the strings, but neither of them work

Comment: So, what is the exact string you are passing in? Does it have to be a single string, and not a more standard array or something?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson In my case, it's a single string.

Answer (score 1):

`var1 varchar2(1000) := 'a','b','c'` -  Incorect
`var1 varchar2(1000)  := q'~ 'a','b','c'~';`  - correct
`var1 varchar2(1000)  :=  'a,b,c';`- correct

`somthing in (varchar2_variable) is incorrect`. There is no such construciton in oracle .;

Example simple solutions. But both solutions can cause problem in future. More flexible is version with `regexp`

```
declare 
 var1 varchar2(1000)  := q'~ 'a','b','c' ~';
 to_test varchar2(100) := 'a';
begin 
 if instr(var1,to_test) > 0 then 
   dbms_output.put_line('Matched');
 end if; 
end;  

declare 
 var1 varchar2(1000)  := q'~ 'a','b','c' ~';
 to_test varchar2(100) := 'a';
begin 
 if regexp_instr(var1,to_test) > 0 then 
   dbms_output.put_line('Matched');
 end if; 
end;
```

Comment: I think you haven't got my question properly. var_1 variable is a C# variable which passes during the PLSQL method call happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass in an array then this becomes much simpler.

Create an array type if you don't already have one:

```
create or replace type shortlist as table of varchar2(100);
```

Use that as the parameter instead of a plain string:

```
create or replace procedure x
    ( val_1 in shortlist )
is
    val_2 varchar2(1) := 'A';
begin
    if val_2 member of val_1 then
        dbms_output.put_line('matched');
    end if;
end;
```

Call the procedure:

```
begin
    x(shortlist('A','B','C'));
end;
```

or define the array in C# somehow (I don't know C#)

```
string[] names = new string[3] {"A", "B", "C"};
```

and call the procedure as described here: [Passing array to Oracle procedure from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40279185/passing-array-to-oracle-procedure-from-c-sharp)