# How would I extend INTERSECT for an arbitrary number of intersections in a stored procedure?

Tags: plsql

I have a table like `StockItem { StoreId, ItemId }` (where both fields are foreign keys), which details all items stocked in each store.

To answer the question "which stores stock X *and* Y" I can use INTERSECT like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FindStoresStockingBothItems  (
   X IN NUMBER, Y IN NUMBER
) AS 
BEGIN    
    select StoreId from StockItem where ItemId = X
    INTERSECT
    select StoreId from StockItem where ItemId = Y;
END;
```

My use case is to call from C# in a method like `List<int> FindStoresStockingBothItems(int x,int y)`

But what if I want to extend this to a variable number of items? My C# method signature might now be `List<int> FindStoresSellingAllItems(List<int> items)` but I've no idea how to do this in PL/SQL - either how to do the multiple intersections or how to pass in a variable number of input item Ids.

What might a PL/SQL stored procedure look like?

Comment: One way is to move the procedure into a package in order to declare the array type needed. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40344214/2270762. Another option would be to pass the IDs as a comma-separated string. Please see my answer for this.

Comment: Thanks for the link I hadn't even realised this part was a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution, albeit not beautiful, would be to pass a string with the values:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FindStoresStockingBothItems (p_ids VARCHAR2) AS 
  v_storeid INTEGER;
BEGIN    
  SELECT storeid
  INTO v_storeid
  FROM stockitem
  WHERE ',' || p_ids || ',' LIKE '%,' || ItemId || ',%'
  GROUP BY storeid
  HAVING COUNT(*) = REGEXP_COUNT(p_ids, ',') + 1;
END;
```

Comment: your example doesn't appear to address the intersections part, only the input parsing - once I've _got_ my input (by whichever method) how can I combine an arbitrary number of intersects?

Comment: It does. The `HAVING` clause makes sure to return only store IDs that include all requested item IDs.

Comment: Oh I see - thanks. I shall give it a test, thanks